# Huge code base in ASP.NET WebSite leads to performance issue

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-debugging

I have a software compiler (this is a legacy tool that will take clients requirements in to a Excel and at build generated a full database withe the schema that client mentioned in Excel and also generate C# classes and all relevant code files to build a site out of it.) which will generate a Code base for any client requirement. This Code base will contain a ASP.NET Website Project with few class library projects. in this ASP.NET Website project it contains about 5000+ classes in **App_Code** folder so it is almost impossible for me to run this application on my local in debug mode. I will be lucky if I can open the full site in Visual Studio

I have worked on many big projects earlier but this is first time I see like **5000+ classes** files in **App_Code** and **5000+ classes** in **class libraries**. My question is

1. Is this normal? Is this considered as acceptable approach of architecturing your solution?
2. If it is acceptable approach how do I debug it locally with minimum efforts.

I am using Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate, Code is in .NET 4.0

Comment: `App_Code` with 5000+ classes did you saw size of `App_Code's` DLL it may be in `LOTS OF MB`

Comment: @Ganesh_Devlekar bin is 810 MB only DLLs in bin is about 340 MB

Comment: First thing I would do is stop using web site "projects". They're not projects and they are very different from all of the real project types in Visual Studio.

Comment: @JohnSaunders unfortunately this (Web Site) is the output the legacy compiler tools generates. I have no control on changing it.

Comment: Well, then, you're kind of SOL. Unless you can use a different tool to convert the web sites into web application projects... No chance of the tool changing, or of using a different tool? Web sites were never meant for things like this.

Comment: Among other things, they were not meant for lazy code generators that put all their code into App_Code. The generator should have generated one or more separate class library projects for most of the code.

Comment: @JohnSaunders lets say I manually convert this website to web Project and create multiple class libraries for App_Code classes. Now what is the decent amount (maximum) of classes I can have in each class library?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64506/discussion-between-habo-and-john-saunders).

Comment: There are no practical limits to the number of classes in a class library. It's more a matter of organization. You'll want to separate, say, repository from business logic from entities from services.